# Removing from Control but Keeping Layer on the Map

Tags: jquery, controls, leaflet, layer

I have a Leaflet.js based web page at http://gisdev.clemson.edu/fireflies . In the top right corner are layers' controls.  I would like to be able to to remove the options like 'states' from the layers' control box but still keeping the states' layer visible. If I don't add the 'states' object to the map's overlay then that layer doesn't get visible on the map.

I have thought of using jQuery to remove the option but an wondering if there is a better way--some kind of built-in within the Leaflet framework.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a layer to the map without adding it to the control.

Looking at your Fireflies application, if you want to remove the states layer from the layer control while still having it display on the map, simply remove the states key/val from your overlays object.

You are already adding the states layer to the map with the following

```
var wmsstates = L.tileLayer.wms("http://jomdev.clemson.edu:8080/geoserver/it.geosolutions/wms", {
    layers: 'it.geosolutions:USA_States',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "usastates"
});

wmsstates.addTo(map);
```

At this point it's already been added to the map.  So now all you have to do is not add it to the Layer Control.

So, instead of this

```
var overlays = {    
    "Counties": wmscounty,
    "States": wmsstates,
    "Fireflies": geojsonFirefly
};

layersControl = new L.Control.Layers(baseLayers, overlays, {
    collapsed: false,
    id: 'irfancontrols'
});
```

Use this

```
var overlays = {    
    "Counties": wmscounty
    "Fireflies": geojsonFirefly
};

layersControl = new L.Control.Layers(baseLayers, overlays, {
    collapsed: false,
    id: 'irfancontrols'
});
```

Since the States layer is no longer an overlay, it might be hidden underneath your basemap.  To solve this you'll want to call `bringToFront`

```
wmsstates.bringToFront();
```

Great looking project BTW.  :)

Comment: Thanks and thanks! But if I use your way--omitting to add the States in the overlays then States don't show on the map! I have already tried that. Even tried changing order in the overlay stack but still no good. BTW, I have figured now out a jQuery solution to this but would still prefer a built-in one.

Comment: @Meengla - I see the problem, with states no longer listed among the overlays, the layer can get hidden beneath the basemap.  I added another line the code in my answer that shows how you can position that layer on top of the other basemaps (with bringToFront).

Comment: Hi, I think I did try the bringToFront() as well before and I don't think that had worked. Problem is: I need to not show BOTH the 'States' and the 'Fireflies' layers in the layer's Control box and so applying bringToFront() on both maybe problematic? Thanks again.

Comment: @Meengla - To help solve your problem, you might also try adjusting the transparency to better understand what layers are actually on the map - `layer.setOpacity(.5)`

Comment: @Meengle - and no, I don't think calling bringToFront on both your states layer and fireflies layer should be problematic unless one is covering up the other (and your layers look like line and point layers)

Comment: Okay, I may give it a try later. I think I should mark your answer as correct.  BTW, just updated the webpage per my Question and you can now see the jquery way to remove some controls; you can also see how I am using (rather convoluted way) to make the overlay's checkboxes work like radio buttons. I am still working on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Answer by @sfletche works. Alternately, I am able to make this work by using jQuery. Here is my jQuery solution:

```
$('label').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'States') {//Remove the States
        //$(this).parent().remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Fireflies') {// Remove the Fireflies
        //$(this).parent().remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```